# Access import on child class?

Tags: php, laravel

On my parent I've declared:

```
use App\Models\User as MyUser;

class MyParentController extends MyChildController
```

But how can I access `MyUser` on my child extended class?

I've tried `$this->` and `parent::` with no luck.

Comment: ```MyUser::something()```? To me it is unclear what exactly you want here, could you please clarify your question.

Comment: I just want to access the `MyUser` model in `MyChildController`

Comment: You will need to include the `use App\Models\User as MyUser;` in the `MyChildController` if you want to use in one of it's methods.

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme ok, if that is the case, it needs to be dynamic on the parent, best way to make it dynamic on the parent and refer to it on the child?

Comment: @panthro I posted a answer, see if it helps =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to access in MyUser

For static method

```
MyUser::methodYouWantToAccess();
```

For dynamic

```
$myUser = new MyUser();
```

Comment: Static method on model, I've tried `MyUser::methodYouWantToAccess();` but just get a class not found error.

Comment: Are you sure that the path to User is correct "App\Models\User"
Maybe to reduce complexity try to use it with it's original name,
`
`use App\Models\User;`
`class MyParentController extends MyChildController `
`{
 $var = User::method()
}`

Comment: Also check that your User class has no syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

First thing:

`class MyParentController extends MyChildController`: this says that the `MyParentController` will Inheritance from `MyChildController`.

If you want to `MyParentController` to be the base controller you will define it like this:

```
use App\Models\User as MyUser;
class MyParentController{
    $my_user = new MyUser();//You will have to instantiate the MyUser in the father class.

}
```

An then, on your child controller, you will use like this:

```
use "Insert path to your controllers"\MyParentController;

class MyChildController extends MyParentController{
    //in this controller you will use like this
    $my_user->methodYouWantToAccess();
}
```